# What is DoAuthorization in Paypal for?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am doing test regarding Paypal sandbox server about Express Checkout, and found the following weird situation.

In Paypal documentation, if I use `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION = 'Order'`, I need to call `DoAuthorization` before call `DoCapture` to collect money. It's good, as we can collect the money when the customer got the product.

However, after test, I've found I can call `DoCapture` directly by using the `PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID` to capture money from my sandbox test personal account to sandbox test business account.

It's really weird. So, should I really need to call `DoAuthorization` before `DoCapture`? What's the meaning of `DoAuthorization`? Or because it is sandbox server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DoAuthorization` should be called before `DoCapture` if the transaction is of `PAYMENTACTION=Order`. If `PAYMENTACTION=Authorization`, you can immediately call `DoCapture` on this.

As far as I'm aware you shouldn't be able to run `PAYMENTACTION=Order` and an immediate `DoCapture`, so that could be a Sandbox fluke I suppose